# what is the spectrum of the operator $T({x_1},{x_2},{x_3}, \ldots ) = ({x_1},\frac{{{x_2}}}{2},\frac{{{x_3}}}{3}, \ldots )$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let us define the operator $T$ over $\ell_2$
$$T({x_1},{x_2},{x_3}, \ldots ) = ({x_1},\frac{{{x_2}}}{2},\frac{{{x_2}}}{3}, \ldots )$$

what is the point spectrum of this operator and the spectrum?

attempt:

what is puzzling me that when I try to get the point spectrum by setting $T(x)=\lambda x$, I end up getting no solution since $\lambda x_n=x_n/n$ for all $n$. if I solve using $x_1$, I get 1, with $x_2$ I get $1/2$ and so on. Should I deduce the spectrum is empty?

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1355228

Comment: what is puzzling me that when I try to get the point spectrum by setting $T(x)=\lambda x$, I end up getting no solution since $\lambda x_n=x_n/n$ for all $n$

Comment: No contradiction in fact : take $(x_1,x_2, ... x_n, \cdots)$ of the form $(0,0, \cdots, 0, 1, 0, \cdots)$ with a single $1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your additional question, consider the "canonical" base vectors of $\ell_2$. This gives you a lot of eigenvalues. Actually, your argument shows that there are no other eigenvalues. If you know a theorem about the spectrum of compact operators, you can now show that your operator is compact and are done. Otherwise, you have to calculate the resolvent.

Comment: makes perfect sense, and so apparent, how could I miss that!!

Comment: See for self adjointness [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/502286).

Comment: so the point spectrum is the sequence ${\left\{ {\frac{1}{n}} \right\}_{n \in \mathbb N}}$

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks :)

Comment: Does the theorem says that for compact operators the spectrum consists only of the point spectrum? what is the name of theorem exactly?

Comment: Yes, there is a theorem which says that all **nonzero** spectral values are eigenvalues. Zero may or may not be an eigenvalue, but it belongs to the spectrum if the space has infinite dimension. I do not think that the theorem has a particular name.

Comment: @MartinVäth but then I have to prove first the operator is compact. Probably self-adjointness would help with that.

Comment: The theorem I mentioned does not necessarily hold for self-adjoint operators unless they are compact. And self-adjointness usually does not help in proving compactness.
You can still go the alternative way and calculate the resolvent: If $\lambda\ne\frac1n$ and $\lambda\ne0$, consider $Ax-\lambda x=y$ coordinate-wise and show that it implies $x=R(\lambda)y$ for some bounded operator $R(\lambda)$ in $\ell_2$ (and that the corresponding $x$ satisfies the equation).

Comment: @MartinVäth Let me get you straight. You want me to find the resolvent set, the set of $\lambda$ for which the $R(\lambda)$ exist, and bounded, but I think we also have to make sure that the domain of $R(\lambda)$ is dense in in $\ell^2$, which I do not know how to do. After finding the resolvent, then the spectrum is $C \setminus \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is in the resolvent set.

Comment: By "$R(\lambda)$ is a bounded operator in $\ell_2$" I mean that the domain is $\ell_2$, that is, your calculation (hence definition of $R(\lambda)y$) works for every $y\in\ell_2$. Just try to calculate $R(\lambda)y$ by writing $Ax-\lambda x=y$ in coordinates, and you should be able understand what I mean.

Comment: @MartinVäth ok, thanks. What about the zero, is it in the spectrum?

Comment: As the space is infinite-dimensional and the operator is compact, it is in the spectrum. You can also argue that the spectrum must be closed (in the complex plane) and that $\frac1n$ are in the spectrum.